# Asymptotic distribution of white noise ACF

Tags: time-series, white-noise

I (encountered this in my lecture) wonder why do we want the autocorrelation of our residuals to be mostly within 2 s.d. as a sign that residuals are consistent white noise?

More specifically

1. why do we want the autocorrelation of our residuals to be mostly within 2 s.d.? shouldn't the white noise be as less correlated/random as possible?
2. what does this consistency mean? and why do we want it to be consistent?

Comment: "s.d." is probably intended as a *standard error,* not a standard deviation.  Thus, "within 2 s.d. [of zero]" can be interpreted as a rough way of testing whether the data are consistent with zero autocorrelation at all lags.  But if you think "s.d." was really intended as "standard deviation," then it would help us to have more context or a clear characterization of what this is and how it is computed.

Comment: @whuber The slides I was looking at states this: if $\{X_t\}_t$ is weak stationary white noise, then for large $n$, its autocorrelation $\rho (h)$ distribution is approximately standard normal with variance$\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is the length of the time series data

Comment: Yes, this is a standard approximation.  It's used to erect reference lines in the plot produced by the `acf` function in `R`, for example. The square root of that variance is the standard error.  Very generally, most statistical estimates will be within a couple of SEs of their actual values: that's all that's going on here.